# Doing HTTP requests FROM Laravel to an external API

Tags: php, http, laravel, request

What I want is get an object from an API with a HTTP (eg, jQuery's AJAX) request to an external api. How do I start? I did research on Mr Google but I can't find anything helping.

Im starting to wonder is this is even possible?
In this post [Laravel 4 make post request from controller to external url with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770184/laravel-4-make-post-request-from-controller-to-external-url-with-data) it looks like it can be done. But there's no example nor any source where to find some documentation.

Please help me out?

Comment: You can use Httpful : Website : http://phphttpclient.com/ Github : https://github.com/nategood/httpful

Comment: If still interested you can also use Curl for this, I'd guess you could say curl is the jquery ajax for PHP in some form.

Comment: You can use [Laravel's HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client).

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Based upon an answer of a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695523/1412268

Take a look at [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
echo $res->getBody(); // { "type": "User", ....
```

Comment: Also see the answer of Jeremie Ges,  
Looks great, although it doesn't answer my question in fact about a Laravel kinda way, I will sure look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @Chilion, Al Snoek WAS directing you toward an official Laravel package. It is pre-installed in the laravel vendor group.

Comment: i m getting a Stream object instead of json string. can someone help me?

Comment: I doing the same thing but my browser turn infinitely

Comment: There is now an easier way in Laravel 7.x: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908329/2341298

Comment: For those who getting stream object instead of JSON use: $res->getBody()->getContents()

Comment: It is possible to redirect on the URL which is called.

Answer (score 112):

We can use package Guzzle in Laravel, it is a PHP HTTP client to send HTTP requests.

You can install Guzzle through composer

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
```

Or you can specify Guzzle as a dependency in your project's existing composer.json

```
{
   "require": {
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
   }
}
```

Example code in laravel 5 using Guzzle as shown below,

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class yourController extends Controller {

    public function saveApiData()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://url_to_the_api', [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => 'test_id',
                'secret' => 'test_secret',
            ]
        ]);
        echo $res->getStatusCode();
        // 200
        echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
        // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
        echo $res->getBody();
        // {"type":"User"...'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also see my comment below my post;  
     
Long time later, created a really small tut how to use Guzzle. From aisnoek his answer. chilion.nl/laravel-post-requests-with-guzzle –  Chilion Aug 19 at 12:09    √

Comment: Your comment `// "200"` should be `// 200` because the returned value is an integer.

Answer (score 69):

As of **Laravel v7.X**, the framework now comes with a minimal API wrapped around the [Guzzle HTTP client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). It provides an easy way to make **get**, **post**, **put**, **patch**, and **delete** requests using the [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('http://test.com');
$response = Http::post('http://test.com');
$response = Http::put('http://test.com');
$response = Http::patch('http://test.com');
$response = Http::delete('http://test.com');
```

You can manage responses using the set of methods provided by the `Illuminate\Http\Client\Response` instance returned.

```
$response->body() : string;
$response->json() : array;
$response->status() : int;
$response->ok() : bool;
$response->successful() : bool;
$response->serverError() : bool;
$response->clientError() : bool;
$response->header($header) : string;
$response->headers() : array;
```

Please note that you will, of course, need to install Guzzle like so:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

There are a lot more helpful features built-in and you can find out more about these set of the feature here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client

This is definitely now the easiest way to make external API calls within Laravel.

Comment: This is great! I am using laravel 9x and works awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 63):

You just want to call an external URL and use the results? PHP does this out of the box, if we're talking about a simple GET request to something serving JSON:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://host.com/api/stuff/1'), true);
```

If you want to do a post request, it's a little harder but there's loads of examples how to do this with curl.

So I guess the question is; what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to be able to use all kinds of functions of an REST API. So yes, I will need POST. I thought (hoped...) that Laravel would have some methods to do it in a Laravel kinda way, but I'll stick to PHP then. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not need the result, just trying to HIT the API or PING a URL, this is the best approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

Add `GuzzleHttp` package using `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.3.3`

Or you can specify Guzzle as a dependency in your project's `composer.json`

```
{
   "require": {
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.3.3"
   }
}
```

Include below line in the top of the class where you are calling the API

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Add below code for making the request

```
$client = new Client();

$res = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.exmple.com/mydetails', [
    'form_params' => [
        'name' => 'george',
    ]
]);

if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) { // 200 OK
    $response_data = $res->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Definitively, for any PHP project, you may want to use GuzzleHTTP for sending requests.
Guzzle has very nice documentation you can check [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).
I just want to say that, you probably want to centralize the usage of the Client class of Guzzle in any component of your Laravel project (for example a trait) instead of being creating Client instances on several controllers and components of Laravel (as many articles and replies suggest).

I created a trait you can try to use, which allows you to send requests from any component of your Laravel project, just using it and calling to `makeRequest`.

```
namespace App\Traits;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
trait ConsumesExternalServices
{
    /**
     * Send a request to any service
     * @return string
     */
    public function makeRequest($method, $requestUrl, $queryParams = [], $formParams = [], $headers = [], $hasFile = false)
    {
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
        ]);

        $bodyType = 'form_params';

        if ($hasFile) {
            $bodyType = 'multipart';
            $multipart = [];

            foreach ($formParams as $name => $contents) {
                $multipart[] = [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'contents' => $contents
                ];
            }
        }

        $response = $client->request($method, $requestUrl, [
            'query' => $queryParams,
            $bodyType => $hasFile ? $multipart : $formParams,
            'headers' => $headers,
        ]);

        $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Notice this trait can even handle files sending.

If you want more details about this trait and some other stuff to integrate this trait to Laravel, check this [article](https://medium.com/@JuanDMeGon/consume-any-http-service-from-laravel-the-good-way-e523034e9ad0?source=friends_link&sk=fdd34a5959b080e0ad3114f5aea2a9b0). Additionally, if interested in this topic or need major assistance, you can take [my course](https://www.udemy.com/course/http-client-laravel-guzzle-requests-consume-apis-services/?couponCode=STACKOVERFLOW) which guides you in the whole process.

I hope it helps all of you.

Best wishes :)

Answer (score 4):

I also created trait similar to @JuanDMeGonthat's that u can use anywhere in your project.Please check this out

```
trait ApiRequests
{
    public function get($url, $data = null)
    {
        try {
            $response = Http::get($this->base_url . $url, $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            info($e->getMessage());
            abort(503);
        }

        if ( $response->status() == 401) {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        } else if (! $response->successful()) {
           abort(503);
        }

        return $response->json();
    }

    public function post($url, $data = [])
    {
        $token = session()->get('token');
        try {
            $response = Http::acceptJson()->withToken($token)->post($this->base_url . $url, $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            abort(503);
        }

        if ($response->status() == 401 && !request()->routeIs('login')) {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }

        return $response;
    }
 
}

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $base_url;
 
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests, ApiRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->base_url = env("BASE_URL","http://192.168.xxxxxxx");
        
        View::share('base_url', $this->base_url);
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic Solution for Laravel 8 is

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('http://example.com');
```

I had conflict between "GuzzleHTTP sending requests" and "Illuminate\Http\Request;" don't ask me why... [it's here to be searchable]

So looking for 1sec i found in Laravel 8 Doc...

**Guzzle is inside the Laravel 8 Http Request !**

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests

as you can see

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#introduction

> Laravel provides an expressive, minimal API around the Guzzle HTTP
> client, allowing you to quickly make outgoing HTTP requests to
> communicate with other web applications. Laravel's wrapper around
> Guzzle is focused on its most common use cases and a wonderful
> developer experience.

It worked for me very well, have fun and if helpful point up!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple call for laravel **9.4**

```
Route::get('/currency', function () {
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'x-api-key' => 'prtl6749387986743898559646983194',
    ])->get('https://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/v3/culture/currencies');
    return response()->json(['status'=> true,'data'=> json_decode($response->body()), 'Message'=>"Currency retrieved successfully"], 200);
});
```

Don't forget to import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```