# How to import php file to your controller and gather data

Tags: php, laravel, uptime-monitoring

My Controller.

```
public function showMonthlyReport($site_id, $report_id){

$reports = Report::where('report_id', $report_id)->firstOrFail();

$uptime = ???

return view('records', compact('site_id', 'report_id', 'reports', 'uptime'));

}
```

And my UptimeRobot.php reference https://uptimerobot.com/api `getMonitors()`method

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.uptimerobot.com/v2/getMonitors",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "Your Api Key",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  "cache-control: no-cache",
  "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

 if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
$data = json_decode($response);
$custom_uptime = ($data->monitors[0]->custom_uptime_ratio);
$uptime = explode("-",$custom_uptime);
}

?>
```

ApiCommand.php

```
public function handle()
    {
    include(app_path() . '/Includes/DeepCrawl.php');  
    include(app_path() . '/Includes/Uptime.php'); 
    include(app_path() . '/Includes/HelloAnalytics.php');

$stringData = ApiCommand::drawGraph($uptime, $dates, $users, $otherResultsRows, $array_issues, $array_pages_breakdown, $array_uncrawled_url, $array_non_200_pages, $array_orphaned_pages, $array_non_indexable_pages, $array_crawl_source_gap, $array_https_http);

Storage::disk('local')->put('hello.txt', $stringData);

}
```

Currently building a laravel web application.

I am just wondering how can i able to gather data from uptimerobot. I'm going to use my controller so I can pass it to my view but I don't know how. I have code below with the curl php type above. Really confused what am I doing new programmer here. Can someone explain if I'm at the right path or is it possible to do in controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write the curl code as a private function in the controller class and call it as you call any other functions

Comment: @RinsadAhmed if I did that the function above where $uptime = ??? should be $uptime = uptimefunction(); something like that?

Comment: Well, as you are inside a class you should use $uptime = $this->uptimefunction();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest slightly different solution:

1. Extract your curl code in a separate [console command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan) and run this command each minute (for example, as a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)).
2. The result of the command save to database/file/memory.
3. In your `showMonthlyReport()` refer to existing result.

Benefits:

- In this way you would not have to wait for your curl result on each `showMonthlyReport()`. All code will run asynchronously
- All errors processing will be in one place
- Command is testable

Comment: @PrisacariDimitrii I already tried that and run successfully but I don't know where to find the result :/

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin You could try to save it to file using `Storage` facade and read the file on `showMonthlyReport()` run. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem for details.

Comment: @PrisacariDimitrii can you have a look on my commands file? going to edit my content above.

Comment: Firstly I would recommend using Guzzle client instead of bare curl (see related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355828/doing-http-requests-from-laravel-to-an-external-api)
Secondly, I would avoid using any `include`s in your command. All code should be written in your laravel app as services. After that you should inject services in your command using dependency injection. If there would be any questions, please create separate question as this discussion gets out of scope.