# How to integrate Sabre Api with laravel

Tags: laravel, sabre

I had been finding a package for laravel 5 to integrate the Sabre Api with my booking system.

The Sabre Api needs authentication and connection with their remote server.

Can anyone help me find a correct solution to integrate the Sabre api with my website built on laravel 5.

Comment: There is unlikely to be any package. I don't even think Sabre provides a vanilla composer package. I implemented the Sabre API into a CakePHP application, but I just built it as a vanilla service within my CakePHP application utilizing GuzzleHttp for interacting with Sabre since its mostly an HTTP POST web service. Roll up your sleaves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a package for this API for Laravel since Sabre is not used by many developers, just a few big companies that use it. But those all probably have their own API they use. The Sabre API is a REST API, which means you can just send requests to the API and translate the JSON objects you get to a PHP object with `json_decode`.

Maybe you can take a look at [Doing HTTP requests FROM Laravel to an external API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355828/doing-http-requests-from-laravel-to-an-external-api) to send requests to Sabre.