# update method issue(The POST method is not supported) in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to create update method and this is the code:

```
Route::get("/allProducts/edit/{id}","AllproductController@edit")->name('Allproduct.edit');
Route::post("/allProducts/update/{id}","AllproductController@update")->name('Allproduct.update');
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                      action="{{ route('allProducts.update' , [ 'id'=>$allproduct->id ]) }}">
                    {{ csrf_field()}}
```

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       $data = Allproduct::find($id);

        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->save();

        return redirect(route('allProducts.index'));
    }
```

when I click on submit button it shows me :

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" error!

what is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doing HTTP requests FROM Laravel to an external API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355828/doing-http-requests-from-laravel-to-an-external-api)

Answer (score 1):

Your route names do not match.

in routes:
name('**Allproduct**.update');

in the form:
**allProducts**.update

Also, you can always check the name of the routes thanks to the console command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

if you want use method PUT:

you can change method in routes:

Route::post to Route::put

and add next in form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

OR

```
@method('PUT')
```

this is if your laravel version is 6 and if your version another, check correct way to use PUT method in forms at [laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing) with your version.

Comment: as i have seen in route list I should use put or patch!but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

So your form should look like this:

`<form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="{{ route('Allproduct.update' , [ 'id'=>$allproduct->id ]) }}">
      @csrf
      @method('PUT')`

You had a typo in your route name and it was missing the `method` field.

Change your route to this:

`Route::put("/allProducts/update/{id}","AllproductController@update")->name('Allproduct.update');`

This will work, but
 i strongly recommend you read this [laravel naming conventions](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions), and then change the name of your controller and model to AppProductController, AppProduct.