# Processing a php POST request prior sending to API

Tags: php, laravel

I have faced this problem over and over again.

Scenario: I communicate data to some API using a POST request (this time it's a payment form, the user enters some details and gets redirected to a payment gateway to make the actual transaction via credit card or whatever..), so far so good.

One of the fields commonly required by the APIs in this scenario is a *hash* field or such, (Basically a field that md5 hashes some of the fields entered + a **secret** merchant key).

Now..

The only way to hash these fields + the secret key **securely** is via a server-side language (I use PHP).

I got around this problem by taking the user's original input, processing and hashing it, then prompting the user with a second page, with all the API required fields hidden **it included the hash too** and asked the user to click a "confirm" button basically triggering the POST request with the API's required fields.

Here's the issue: I don't like prompting the user with a second "confirm" page/button.

I'm currently using Laravel, is there a way to take the user's input, process it and hash what needs to be hashed and *automatically* redirect him to the payment gateway without having him click a "confirm" button.

I tried to trigger the confirm button in the second page via jQuery on document ready, to make more of a smooth experience, but browsers consider it popup and block it.

Thanks in advance, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Maybe this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694289/call-external-api-function-from-controller-laravel-4

Comment: @Peh, thanks but as far as I understand, the implementation in the linked question serves a different purpose. (handling a json response via guzzle).