# Laravel 5: how to redirect with data to external resource form controller

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, payment-gateway, payment

I want to send user to payment gate. Normally it could be made by this form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://demo.moneta.ru/assistant.htm">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_ID" value="12345678">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_TRANSACTION_ID" value="000001">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_CURRENCY_CODE" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_AMOUNT" value="123.45">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
```

User press "Pay" and redirect to payment gate.

But I want implement this workflow:

1. User enter delivery info, payment method, etc.
2. After that he press "Pay" and
3. First I want to store data (I do it in my controller)...
4. ... and after that I want redirect user to payment gate.  (this is unclear for me)

The question is: how to redirect user to external resource from controller (method should be POST, and I need do send some data such as MNT_ID, etc. (see form example above)?

Comment: Probably already answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770184/laravel-4-make-post-request-from-controller-to-external-url-with-data

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

call your function controller:

```
public function redirectPOST(){
//params
$USERNAME='username';
return view('your vie', compact('USERNAME'));}
```

then in your view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function closethisasap() {
 document.forms["redirectpost"].submit();
  }
 </script>
  </head>
 <body onload="closethisasap();">
 <form name="redirectpost" method="POST" action="http://URL">
 <input type="hidden" id="USERNAME" name="USERNAME" value="{{$USERNAME}}">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could help you use the Laravel controller as usual and redirect after to the external resource.

In your view redirect the action to your controller:

```
<form method="post" action={{ action('Controller@method') }}>
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_ID" value="12345678">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_TRANSACTION_ID" value="000001">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_CURRENCY_CODE" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="MNT_AMOUNT" value="123.45">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
public function method(Request $request)
{
     // Validate
     // Store
     // ...
     Redirect::away('https://demo.moneta.ru/assistant.htm')->withInputs(Input::all());

}
```

I didn't test it, but I'm pretty sure that it works (or is near to the solution).

You can get other suggestion from the official guide: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects

Comment: `return Redirect::away("https://demo.moneta.ru/assistant.htm")->withInputs(Input::all());` do not help. As I can see in browser's network explorer: request is GET and there is no data in request. BTW, I add `Input::all()` because without it there was an error.

Comment: you're right, this is a GET request and `withInputs()` needs `Input:all()` as parameter. Have you tried to validate the form via AJAX request (so you can validate and store your data) and redirect to the external url browser side?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to an external URL with Laravels's redirect.
First import the Redirect to your controller and

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
return Redirect::away($redirectUrl)->with(['user_id'=>$user_id]);
```

would help you to send the request as a post with the needed params.